# Python list comparison of some elements

Tags: python, list, comparison

How can I check if a list is included in another, but just part of it? 
By this I mean:

list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

list_b = [4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 7]

I just want to check if list_b is something like [*, 2, *, 4, *, *, * ].  (* meaning any character/number)

EDIT 1: more specifically, I want to check if a list [*, 2, *, 4, *, *, * ] is included in any other list.

For example it will be included in [1, 4, 5, **2**, 7, **4**, 8]

EDIT 2: 2 being in the second position and 4 in the forth is a coincidence. What I try to achieve is check is a list pattern is included in another list. In the pattern list not all elements are to be included. For example, check if pattern_list = [foo, foo, 8, foo, foo, foo, 7] is included into another list = [foo, foo, foo, foo, foo, 8, foo, foo, foo, 7, foo, foo]

Comment: How have you attempted to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I am unable to related your statement *"How can I check if a list is included in another"* with your example `[*, 2, *, 4, *, *, * ]`. Please explain the logic behind it

Comment: Show us some example code and where you have a specific problem.

Comment: do you want to check that the elements at certain positions have specific values or do you just want to see if the list contains certain values (at any position)?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's unclear what you are asking for, please review [ask] and provide a [mcve]!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list_b = [4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 7]
>>> [x for x,y in zip(list_a, list_b) if x == y]
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def allUnique(L):
    for i in L:
        if i != L[0]: return False
    return True

In [21]: list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [22]: list_b = [4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 7]

In [23]: answer = [t[0] if allUnique(t) else "*" for t in zip(list_a, list_b)]

In [24]: answer
Out[24]: ['*', 2, '*', 4, '*', '*']
```

Comment: `allUnique` is being called on tuples... offers no benefit that I can see over `if t[0] == t[1]`

Comment: @TemporalWolf: it scales better with k-tuples where k>2

Comment: 2 being in the second position and 4 in the forth is a coincidence. What I try to achieve is check is a list pattern is included in another list. In the pattern list not all elements are to be included. For example, Check is pattern_list = [foo, foo, 8, foo, foo, foo, 7] is included into another list.

Comment: @C.P.: `2` is in fact in position 1, because python indices start at 0. In any case, this will work for your other example as well - have you tried it?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget it works for this case, but wouldn't for example if list_b=[1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 7, 7]

Comment: @C.P.: I get `[1, '*', '*', 4, '*', '*']` for `list_b=[1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 7, 7]`. What output do you expect? How is this output different from that? It would be much more helpful if you could explain your concerns more, than just saying "this will not work"

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

`>>>a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

`>>>b = [3, 67, 1]`

`>>>list(set(a).intersection(set(b)))`

`>>>[1, 3]`